# Why doesn't my webscrape code accept cookies

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm a beginner in web scrapping and I've followed a few YouTube videos about how to do this, but regardless to what I try I can't have my code accept the cookies.

This is the code I have so far:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Safari() 
URL = "https://www.zoopla.co.uk/new-homes/property/london/?q=London&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=new-homes&page_size=25&pn=1&view_type=list"
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(2) # Wait a couple of seconds, so the website doesn't suspect you are a bot
try:
    driver.switch_to_frame('gdpr-consent-notice') # This is the id of the frame
    accept_cookies_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="save"]')
    accept_cookies_button.click()

except AttributeError: # If you have the latest version of selenium, the code above won't run because the "switch_to_frame" is deprecated
    driver.switch_to.frame('gdpr-consent-notice') # This is the id of the frame
    accept_cookies_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="save"]')
    accept_cookies_button.click()

except:
    pass # If there is no cookies button, we won't find it, so we can pass
```

Comment: `driver.switch_to_frame(...)` gets not executed, is this intended?

Comment: Ah no, I was trying different things and left that out accidentally. I've edited the question now to include everything

Answer (score 0):

I don't have safari webdriver but chrome webdriver, but I think they works similar. On chrome you close the cookie banner with this code

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get(URL)
# wait no more than 20 seconds for the `iframe` with id `gdpr-consent-notice` to appear, then switch to it
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "gdpr-consent-notice")))
# click accept cookies button
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#save').click()
```